# IBM Quantum Circuit output probabilities for single Hadamard gate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, probability

I am new to using the IBM Quantum Emulator, and I encounter this result which I don't understand:

[image]

The input is a single **0** bit that is passed into a Hadamard gate (click the picture to enlarge). I couldn't understand why the measurement outcome after this is answered as **0** with 100% certainty?

Shouldn't this measurement outcome be 50% **0** and 50% **1** after passing through the single H gate?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with a measurement gate. For some reason, the composer shows one of all possible results but not all of them in case the measurement gate is included into a circuit. It seems that IBM wants the composer to behave like a real measurement, i.e. from one experiment, you obtain only one result.

Try these:

1. remove the measurement gate and you should see 50%/50% probability of occurence for both $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ states.
2. Add the measurement gate back and run your cirucit on a simulator or real quantum processor with number of shots greater than 1. In case of simulator you should see perfect 50%/50% distribution, in case of the real processor, there will be some noise but the distribution will be close to the uniform one.

[image]

Comment: thank you, removing the measurement gate does give the original 50/50 probabiities.